# Llamar datos de Oracle a una Tabla NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, oracle-10g

quisiera ayuda en este tema, por que en realidad no se muy bien como realizarlo.

Mi pregunta es, yo tengo un formulario en mi NetBeans y al dar clic en el boton me debería de jalar los datos que tengo en mi Oracle y mostrarlos en la tabla que tengo allí... ¿como podría hacerlo?, por favor ayuda.

Y otra consulta sería, ¿Aparte de jalar los datos de mi oracle y mostrarlos en la tabla, como podría jalar un datos...pero de esos datos del oracle mostrar un dato en un Jlabel y el resto si que vaya a la tabla?

Necesito su ayuda, por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Busca información sobre JDBC. En todo caso A) no es una "tabla netbeans" porque las "tablas netbeans" no existen; Netbeans solo te da algunas ayuda para "diseñar" una tabla pero por debajo es todo Java puro y duro; recomiendo que te aclares mejor con como funciona Java antes de intentar aprender nuevas funcionalidades y B) este sitio es para preguntas **específicas** en las que muestras qué trabajo has hecho (incluyendo código), mira [help], [ask] y [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que crear un método en tu formulario donde se haga el llenado de tú tabla ejecutando un query donde haga la consulta de la tabla que tienes en tu BD y vaciar dichos datos de la consulta en tu tabla del formulario

Te mostrare un método de ejemplo

```
   void mostrarDatos(){

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("ID");
    model.addColumn("Nombre");
    model.addColumn("Edad");
    model.addColumn("Sexo");

    tabla.setModel(model);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaPersona";

    String datos[] = new String[5];
    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);//Aqui ejecuta la consulta
        while(rs.next()){//Se hace el llenado de la tabla con los datos que se obtienen  de la consulta
            datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
            datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
            datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
            datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
            model.addRow(datos);
        }
        tabla.setModel(model);

        if(tabla.getModel().getRowCount() == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO SE ENCONTRO NINGUNA COINCIDENCIA","AVISO",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            mostrarDatos("");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error en la consulta..." + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(frm_users.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, aun que yo no haya puesto nada de código (fue por que no sabia como era en realidad) no te hiciste problemas como otros y me ayudaste en verdad, te lo agradezco :)